# How to suppress table numbering for 1 table Latex

Tags: tables

I want to include a table at the beginning of my document, which is not counted. So, the second table starts with number 1. All the following tables will then continue with number 2, 3 etc.

How can I do that in latex?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
         &  \\
         & 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption*{Should have no numbering}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
         &  \\
         & 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Should be table 1}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: What gets numbered is captions. No caption, no number.

Comment: you can achieve by setting the counter value of the tables after your first table back to 0, as follows: `\setcounter{table}{0}`

Comment: I am sorry, I did not know my code was not working. The setcounter option works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @G.deMan - Your piece of advice does *not* let the OP achieve his/her goal of generating an unnumbered caption via `\caption*`.

Comment: @DonaldHosek - If I understand the OP's objective correctly, he/she wants to create an un-numbered caption, *not* no caption at all.

Answer (score 5):

In order for `\caption*` to produce an unnumbered caption, the [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package has to be loaded.

[image]

With this setup, there's absolutely no need to fiddle with the `table` counter.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption} % <-- this is important

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]\caption*{Should have no numbering}\end{table}
\begin{table}[h]\caption{Should be table 1}\label{tab:my_label}\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `caption` automatically adds some extra vertical spaces above and below `\caption`, hence changes the default caption style. Here `\usepackage[strut=false]{caption}` is more recommended.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ - Thanks. I guess that what is "recommended" depends very much on what one wants to achieve, typographically speaking. Suppose the objective is to emulate the "look" produced if the `caption` package isn't loaded, in terms of the vertical distance between the caption and the `\hline` at the top of the subsequent `tabular` environment. In that's the case, then running `\usepackage[skip=0pt]{caption}` is probably "recommended".

Comment: Regarding the `\[above|below]captionskip` you mentioned, I think `\usepackage[strut=false, figureposition=below]{caption}` emulates better. That is, in standard document classes, `\abovecaptionskip` is always 10pt and `\below...` is always 0pt. But by default `caption` exchanges the value of them for `\caption` used in `figure` float env. Package option `figureposition=below` restores the exchange. If strict emulation is really needed, one might need option `style=base` as well.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ - The one and only point I tried to make in my answer is that if the OP wants to create an unnumbered caption, then `\caption*` can only do this job if the `caption` package is loaded. AFAICT, the discussion in the preceding comments neither detracts from nor adds to this main point. Let's see if the OP weighs in and provides information about his/her preferences for the "look" of captions,

Comment: I agree with you. My previous comment is already off-topic.